# RxJS 6: Subscribe only onComplete

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I don't care about `next()` or `error()` values. Do I still need to define empty functions as callbacks in `subscribe()` function?

Answer (score 15):

You can do something like this

```
subscribe({
  complete: () => { // do the stuff you need to do on completion }
})
```

`subscribe` allows you to pass an object with 3 properties, `next` `error` and `complete`, which point to the respective functions. Each of this property is optional.

Answer (score 4):

In fact you can use just the following without any handler:

```
.subscribe()
```

However this doesn't handle `error` notifications (these will be thrown to the global error handler) so you might want to use also this to ignore all errors:

```
.subscribe({ error: () => {} })
```

Answer (score 2):

In RxJS 6 this will strip away all notifications beside `complete` and also cause completion on error:

```
obs$.pipe(
    ignoreElements(),
    catchError(() => EMPTY))
.subscribe(null, null, _ => console.log("complete"));
```

You still need to pass empty functions or `undefined` for `next` and `error` in your `subscribe`.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind only on the onComplete event with the "finally" method :-

```
myObservable.finally(onCompleteHandler);
```

You can look it here : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/finally.md

Comment: But that will fire on both observer.error() and observer.complete()

Comment: Note also that finally does not trigger the execution of `myObservable`. You still need to subscribe to it at the end.

Comment: method does not exist on type Observable

Answer (score 0):

you can still set

```
.subscribe(undefined, undefined, () => {/* On complete */})
```

to omit any not needed executions of `subscribe`